# Understanding fourier notation $F(\partial_x)$

Tags: notation, fourier-analysis, partial-derivative

Can somebody please help me understand some of the notion in the equations below, taken from a published paper on image de-blurring.

I have an energy $E(H)$ defined over an image $H$, a point-spread function $f$.
$$
E(H) \propto || f \otimes H - \tilde{H} ||^2_2 + \lambda_1(||\Phi(\partial_xH)||_1+||\Phi(\partial_yH)||_1 (1)
$$

where $\partial_xH$ and $\partial_yH$ respectively denote the values of the x and y direction gradient and $\lambda_1$ is a weight.

During optimization, variables $\mu = (\mu_x, \mu_y)$ are used as a substitute for $\partial H=(\partial_xH, \partial_yH)$, and an additional term is added to measure the difference between $\partial H$ and $\mu$, so Eq(1) can be approximated by:

$$
E(H, \mu) = || f \otimes H - \tilde{H}||^2_2 +\lambda_1(||\Phi(\mu_x)||_1 + ||\Phi(\mu_y)||_1) + \lambda_2(||\mu_x - \partial_x H||^2_2 + ||\mu_y - \partial_y H||^2_2) (2)
$$

The energy is minimized using a multi-step procedure, the second part of which involves minimizing $E(H)$ using fourier transforms after fixing $\mu$, Eq(2) becomes:

$$
E(H) = || f \otimes H - \tilde{H}||^2_2 + \lambda_2(||\mu_x - \partial_x H||^2_2 + ||\mu_y - \partial_y H||^2_2)
$$

All the terms in the above function are in quadratic forms, so applying Plancherels's theorem to the above derivation to get:

$$
E(H) = || \mathcal{F}(f) \circ \mathcal{F}(H) - \mathcal{F}(\tilde{H})||^2_2 +
$$
$$
\lambda_2(||\mathcal{F}(\mu_x) - \mathcal{F}(\partial_x) \circ \mathcal{F}
(H)||^2_2 +||\mathcal{F}(\mu_y) - \mathcal{F}(\partial_y)\circ\mathcal{F}(H)||^2_2)
$$

Can somebody please explain what is meant by $\mathcal{F}(\partial_x)$? If it was written as $\mathcal{F}(\partial_x H)$ than I understand that is simply the Fourier transform of the horizontal image gradients, but what is $\mathcal{F}(\partial_x)$?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that they are trying to say that Fourier transformation of a gradient of a function is the same as multiplying that function by the independent variable.  Specifically, in your case

$$\mathcal{F}(\partial_x) = i k_x$$

when

$$\mathcal{F}(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy\: f(x,y) e^{i k_x x + i k_y y}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help Ron! Sorry if this is a dumb question (I'm not a mathematician by trade, and was never taught anything about Fourier transforms), but what does $k_x$ represent here? I'm trying to translate terms such as $\overline{\mathcal{F}(\partial_x)}\circ\mathcal{F}(\mu_x)$ and  $\overline{\mathcal{F}(\partial_x)}\circ\mathcal{F}(\partial_x)$ into operations that I can apply to an array generated with FFT.

Comment: $k_x$ is the spatial frequency in $x$, which is a kinda-sorta derivative (it represents the relative amounts of variation in your image).  I'm surprised that someone with no knowledge of FTs is having this high-falutin' discussion being thrown at them.  You really should review the basics (like the convolution theorem, etc.) before trying to take on something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the theorem, I think I've got it now.

Comment: @user74325: good.  If my answer was useful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the check mark.